# Android graphics API with JUnit

Tags: java, android, junit, awt, bitmapfactory

I'm currently working on a project that uses sensory input (acc, mag and gyro) to produce a specific result. We developed a test bench with JUnit that will load previously recorded samples containing sensor events and feed them to our algorithm. That algorithm also needs to use a provided map image. Doing this in the device is fairly simple with bitmapFactory.

The issue is doing the same in the JUnit tests, since the bitmap factory is mocked in local JVM tests and the native java package required to do this (AWT) is not available in the Android API.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method decodeByteArray in android.graphics.BitmapFactory not mocked.
```

What is the best way to retrieve the image information in this scenario? I have a byte[] with the image data ready on both the device and test scenarios:

```
protected abstract HashMap<Point2i, MapLabel> openImage(byte[] img, int height, int width);
```

The Android in device implementation uses something like:

```
@Override
protected HashMap<Point2i, MapLabel> getSchematic(byte[] imgFile) {
    Bitmap mapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgFile, 0, imgFile.length);
    int x_dim = mapImage.getWidth();
    int y_dim = mapImage.getHeight();
    HashMap<Point2i, MapLabel> parsedMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(int x = 0; x < x_dim; x++) {
       ...
    }

    return parsedMap;
}
```

For the test implementation i have no idea how to do it, since i don't have any tools that allow me to check the pixel's values in the input image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One word:

Robolectric

Robolectric stubs out Android API for Unit Testing.
It is also very simple to use.

Comment: Some time ago i've actually tried that solution. The issue is that Robolectric BitmapFactory implementation don't actually return the bitmap i provide as byte[]. Instead it returns a fixed 100*100 bitmap, regardless the input.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robolectric/Q0cY7-UYICY/IFDiFRc01iIJ

Comment: Try the new version. The did a huge overhaul lately.

Comment: Yes, i've checked with the latest 3.0 version and it still the same. Thanks anyway